# Why does VSCode not show errors in English?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I prefer learning about programming in English, but VSCode just makes that a lot harder.

For some reason, everything but errors are shown in English.

[image]

Comment: Looking at your taskbar I can see that your system language is Spanish. Try digging in VSCode preferences or google how to override the language

Answer (score 0):

I searched the settings for the Workbench and language and there was no setting for the UI language.

There is a command line argument to change the display language:

Try to start VSC with

```
code --locale en-US .
```